# How To setOnClickListener to a background image at certain cordinates in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, mouseevent, background-image

Hey I'm currently creating a back option to my program. I would like it so that when they user clicks the top left of the background image it will bring you back to the last page. I'm not really sure how I would go about doing so. I know that you can create setOnMouseClicked to buttons but can you do it for a background image and can you specify the cordinates aswell?
here is my code

```
public class Home extends StackPane{

    public Home(){
          javafx.scene.image.Image sizeBG = new 
          javafx.scene.image.Image("file:src/Images/Background.jpg");
          BackgroundSize bSize = new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO, false, false, true, false);
          this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(sizeBG, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, bSize)));


           bSize.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
                MainScene.mainStage.setScene(new IntroScene());
           });
     }
}
```

Here is a reference of my background image. the top left arrow is what I would like to click
[image]

Comment: Just use `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` in the handler, and only perform the action if they are in the range you need.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate the help, I got it too work now

Comment: Another option is to add a button to the top left corner.